# String not being thrown

Tags: c#, exception, throw

I am fairly new to C#. Although throwing the exceptions for the other conditions work fine, the string (or lack of entry would be a better term to use) does not work. It instead goes straight to catch (FormatException) message.

I know that I could put the same statement **if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")** in the aforementioned catch statement, and it would work fine, but I am really curious as to why I cannot do this by throwing a new exception.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        decimal subtotal = Decimal.Parse(txtSubtotal.Text);
        {
            if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
                throw new Exception("Subtotal is a Required Field.");

            if (subtotal <= 0)
                throw new Exception("Subtotal must be greater than 0");

            if (subtotal >= 10000)
                throw new Exception("Subtotal must be less than 10000");
        }

        decimal discountPercent = .25m;
        decimal discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
        decimal invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;

        discountAmount = Math.Round(discountAmount, 2);
        invoiceTotal = Math.Round(invoiceTotal, 2);

        txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
        txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString();
        txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString();

        txtSubtotal.Focus();
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for the Subtotal field.", "Entry Error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + "\n", "Entry Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions to control logic flow. This is a very bad habit and as a new programmer you should try to avoid doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The method `Decimal.Parse()` will throws FormatExceptions if the parameter(`txtSubtotal.Text`) to the method is not convertible. To avoid this you can You trust [`Decimal.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) for doing the same, without any `try..catch` try the following code:

```
decimal subtotal;
if (Decimal.TryParse(txtSubtotal.Text, out subtotal))
{
    if (subtotal <= 0)
       MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be greater than 0");
    else if (subtotal >= 10000)
        MessageBox.Show("Subtotal must be less than 10000");
    else
    { 
     // Process your code here
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input! Subtotal Expecting a Decimal value");
}
```

Comment: You're missing an `out subtotal` in the `TryParse` call

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here, first I think there is a logic issue confusing your expected result. Take this excerpt...

```
decimal subtotal = Decimal.Parse(txtSubtotal.Text);
{
    if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
    throw new Exception("Subtotal is a Required Field.");
...
```

Decimal.Parse is always going to throw a FormatException on an empty string, or any other value where it can't convert to a decimal. This means the next if condition never gets executed. And if it did get executed, it'll never be true because you just proved it otherwise with a successful Decimal.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to your string being null or empty and the code trying to parse a null or empty string to a Decimal.

It would be better to check the string before trying to parse it. Also you can check the contents of a string easily with the string.IsNullOrWhitespace method from the string class.

Like this:

```
try
{ 
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtSubtotal.Text))
        throw new Exception("Subtotal is a Required Field.");

    decimal subtotal = Decimal.Parse(txtSubtotal.Text); 

    //rest of your code.
```

With the code like this and the string is null or white space, the basic Exception will be thrown...but if the string is a NOT null or white space AND it is not a valid number format either, then the code will throw the FormatException.